# SELECT invalid_field FROM {invalid_table}

Tags: mysql, database, github, drupal, drupal-7

My question is about importing a database from github.

When I run `$ git clone https://github.com/repo/path.git` in the terminal, all the files get imported properly, except for the database file, which contains only:

```
SELECT invalid_field FROM {invalid_table}
```

and cannot be imported into mySQL workbench.

What am I doing wrong? Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: It is exceedingly unlikely that your file was damaged during the cloning process. If you view it in the GitHub web UI does it show the same content?

Comment: Oh shoot it does... is there a way to fix that? (I have an older version of the database)

Comment: The way to fix it is to ensure the correct files are committed :-). But committing a database can be a bad idea. Are you trying to commit the database for your application including data, or just database schema definition files / migrations?

Comment: Oh no! Some data has been committed, as well as database structures.

Comment: I recommend not committing data for many reasons. For example: Most data isn't really part of your application. Different instances might have different data: different accounts on development and production instances, less data in development than production, different data for different clients, etc. Also, many Git hosts (including GitHub) have limits for overall repository size and for individual files. A database can eat that up pretty quickly. Unfortunately, I'm not a Drupal guy so I can't give you much concrete help. Try to commit only the database schema, ideally defined in migrations.

Comment: You can usually [revert](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/undoing-changes/git-revert) a commit if something crazy happens

Comment: This is a shared repo, so I won't want to undo anyone else's work... is there a way to solve the problem retroactively (without killing anyone else's progress)

Comment: Yes, then you would have to manually fix it, and apply those changes in another commit

Comment: Thank you for all your help James! 

Any ideas how would I go about fixing it?

Comment: You're welcome!, and unfortunately I don't have enough knowledge of dealing with database changes in Drupal, I'd suggest you reach out to someone with more knowledge, or create that as a separate issue more specific to Drupal

Answer (score 0):

Is the SQL bound to a specific database via connection string?, perhaps what you pulled is attempting to access a different database?

This appears as a file in the official documentation for the Drupal API [here](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21simpletest%21files%21sql-1.txt/7)

Comment: Thanks for the response! Not sure if I understand your question... When I open the sql file in a text editor it shows - "SELECT invalid_field FROM {invalid_table}" - if that clarifies...

Comment: Any way you can check which database your editor is selecting through it's connection string, and if it is the correct one? we could start there, and if that is correct, check the source in github, and be sure it is matching to what the file is that you have, if not try and see if there is anything from that file that can help you see what is missing

Comment: Hm, I am selecting the database manually (through terminal / mySQL workbench). I've selected the one at 

site/path/docroot/modules/simpletest/files/database.sql - (this is a drupal site)...

Comment: Interesting, I'm looking at the official documentation on the site, [here](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21simpletest%21files%21sql-1.txt/7) and shows what your actually seeing to be a file ( sql-1.txt ), I wonder if the editor is picking that up, or mismatching something, and not opening the .sql, unless something else is going on